# Structural design pattern for MVVM View Model?

Tags: mvvm, design-patterns, inotifypropertychanged

Are there any recommended structural design patterns for MVVM view models that allow different state and functionality to be added to a base object dynamically, but still maintaining the INotifyPropertyChanged on all the related properties? Something like a decorator pattern but mvvm-ready?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  The WPF binding system will use a [custom type descriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.customtypedescriptor.aspx) to interact with the properties of your ViewModel at runtime.  I've used this before to make keys in a KeyValueCollection<T> appear as properties on the collection.

**This has two important benefits.**  It simplifies binding:

`DataContext.SomeCollectionProperty[SomeKey]` can be simplified to `DataContext.SomeCollectionProperty.SomeKey` and, if you make a custom type descriptor for the data context, `DataContext.SomeKey` which is about as simple as it gets.

**And it fixes what I consider a bug**--format strings are rendered even when the property is null.  Using a CTD, you can skip null (and DBNull) properties, ensuring that format strings won't be rendered if the property doesn't exist:

Imagine you have a `double?` that you must render as a dollar amount.  If you use the following binding:  `{Binding Price, FormatString='Price: {0:c}'}` and the Price is null, you get the following in your UI:  `Price: $`.  This is ugly.  However, if `Price` is a PropertyDescriptor-based property on your UI, when the Price is null, you can opt to not to report this property via your CTD.  This prevents the format string from being rendered at all.

Here's a pretty good link at MSDN about [decorating your types with a CTD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171819.aspx).

Comment: I've used this technique before it is a good alternative if you don't have dynamics available to you.

Answer (score 1):

From my experimentation, you can use the ExpandoObject in .NET 4 to handle what you want. ExpandoObject implements INPC. I've been creating a DynamicViewModel based on the ExpandoObject that does a few other things like calculated Properties that have dependencies on each other and Delegate Command registration.

Comment: I've tried doing that before, but the pipework was a bit more than I wanted to deal with at that time.  Do you have any good resources about implementing an expando?

Comment: The out of box ExpandoObject works as is. I derive from DynamicObject directly in order to add additional functionality. I'll share a blog post on the technique soon and update this post when I do.

Comment: Well I thank you both for the replies. Kind of upsetting though that there is no design pattern, for example from the GOF, that you use - it's resorting to attributes and trickery?

Comment: You do realize that the GoF book was written 16 years ago? Programming Patterns were never meant to be static, languages change, the industry changes. New patterns are discovered and evolve that take advantage of what's available. You could call it trickery, but it's just taking advantage of what's available in the language and framework.